# Getting Quickly to use Gvim instead of Gedit

Tags: application-development, gedit, vim, quickly, gvim

How do I get [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly) to use Gvim (or just vim in a terminal) as its default text editor instead of Gedit?

If this can be done, I must be doing it wrong...

Ubuntu 10.10 AMD64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to change the editor that Quickly loads when you ask it to.

Well I did some sleuthing... I'll show you what I did followed by the answer.

1. I fired off this command:

   ```
   sudo find / -name "*quickly*" -exec grep gedit {} \;
   ```

   That searches for all files with quickly in and then greps them for gedit. It was a long shot -- I should have refined the search so it was any *paths* with quickly in but it matched!

   ```
   Binary file /usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/quicklyutils.pyc matches
       editor = "gedit"
   ```
2. I opened up `/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/quicklyutils.py` (not the compiled version) in nano, searched for gedit and saw:

   ```
   def get_quickly_editors():
       '''Return prefered editor for ubuntu-application template'''

       editor = "gedit"
       default_editor = os.environ.get("EDITOR")
       if not default_editor:
           default_editor = os.environ.get("SELECTED_EDITOR")
       if default_editor:
          editor = default_editor
       return editor
   ```
3. From that you can see it asks for the environment value `EDITOR`!

   Just run your quickly commands as:

   ```
   env EDITOR=gvim quickly edit
   ```

   or export it to persist

   ```
   export EDITOR=gvim
   quickly edit
   ```

   Add the export line to your `~/.bashrc` line if you want it to persist between sessions.

Comment: Just tested it and it appears to work for all the default templates.

Comment: Yes! I had this! Figured out it was a stupid mistake in .bashrc. [high-five] thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After you install GVim , using Synaptic Package Manager, then it should be available in the Applications menu and you can right click on it and  add the application shortcut to your desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, I can run Gvim quite well. The issue is running it through Quickly (it's like ruby on rails, but for python and developed by Ubuntu) which generally uses Gedit as default.

Comment: I answered this question before "brews" had capitalized the word "Quickly" in his question and provided a link.

Answer (score 1):

What about `sudo update-alternatives –config editor`?
It will change the system default editor so you do not have to change individual program preferences..

From: [Old article, but should still work..](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-the-default-editor-from-nano-on-ubuntu-linux/)