# How to use Sublime Text 2 as Quickly default editor?

Tags: application-development, quickly, text-editor, sublime-text

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22019/getting-quickly-to-use-gvim-instead-of-gedit) answer to change the editor used with quickly and it worked, however now,when I type `quickly edit` the command line stays on the open and does not allow me to enter other commands as long as Sublime Text 2 is open. I realise this is a daft question, but I can't seem to find a way to get around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `EDITOR` environment variable to sublime and then `quickly edit` will use it:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/subl
```

- [How do I set environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables)

Just add the above line to your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: @borax12 It's perhaps better to add it to `~/.profile`, since adding it to `~/.bashrc` won't set it for login shells.

Comment: … or even into `~/.bash_login` if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

It does this because gedit is programmed to do that when you run it from the command line. You can make quickly do that with other editors by using `quickly edit &`.

**Edit**: I wrote a Perl script that will run the editor as a as a child of init so when you close the terminal the editor will remain open: [script](http://ubuntuone.com/3gEAi4L1FHnGv8i9LWvLwk)

You can set the following vaiables at the top of the script:

- command: the command to be run
- stdout: The standard output to be passed to the command (must be set or it will still output to terminal)
- stderr: The standard output to be passed to the command (must be set or it will still output to terminal)

Comment: That still makes the instance dependent on the terminal being open

Comment: I wrote a script to work around that, details above.

Comment: Thanbk you! That's great help :)

Comment: Your script link is dead due to the loss of ubuntuone.com I realize this is an old answer but is there any chance of making this answer valid again?